# Optimized way to Convert file name into full directory path using nested directory for large file storage

Tags: java

What is the optimized way to

Convert `1234567` file name to `12//34//56//1234567.jpg` in java.

or say

```
12.jpg -> 12.jpg
123.jpg -> 12//123.jpg
123456.jpg -> 12//34//123456.jpg
```

So that it can be stored in that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll` like so :

```
String str = "1234567";
String path = str.replaceAll("(..)(..)(..).*", "$1//$2//$3//$0.jpg");
=> 12//34//56//1234567.jpg
```

If you mean digits you can replace your regex like so `"(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).*"`

---

[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kYQ9aS/1)

---

**Edit after OP comment**

In this you can use solution with streams like so :

```
String[] strs = {"1234567", "12345678"};
for (String str : strs) {
    String path = Arrays.stream(str.split("(?<=\\G.{2})"))
            .filter(s -> s.length() == 2)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("//"))
            .concat("//")
            .concat(str)
            .concat(".jpg");
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
12//34//56//1234567.jpg
12//34//56//78//12345678.jpg
```

---

If the name contains the extensions you can use this way instead :

```
String[] strs = {"12.jpg", "123.jpg", "123456.jpg"};
for (String str : strs) {
    String path = Arrays.stream(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(".")).split("(?<=\\G.{2})"))
            .filter(s -> s.length() == 2)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("//"))
            .concat("//")
            .concat(str);
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
12//12.jpg
12//123.jpg
12//34//56//123456.jpg
```

Comment: generic solution? updated question for more details.

Comment: @AnonymousCreator check my answer now